# Discover Mapped Network Drives as Administrator

Tags: c#, wmi, admin, network-drive

I have a c# app that has to be run as an administrator. Next to a lot of other things, the application has to read the mapped network drives.

I wanted to do this with WMI and Win32_NetworkConnection, BUT this only works as a non admin.

Is there a workaround? What would be my best option?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is the code i have that returns an empty list even though 3 network drives are connected:

```cs
public IEnumerable<NetworkConnection> GetNetworkConnections()
{
    List<NetworkConnection> networkConnections = new List<NetworkConnection>();

    try
    {
        var path = new ManagementPath();
        path.NamespacePath = "\\ROOT\\CIMV2";
        path.ClassName = "Win32_NetworkConnection"; //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394220(v=vs.85).aspx

        var management = new ManagementClass(path);

        foreach (ManagementObject obj in management.GetInstances())
        {
            NetworkConnection networkConnection = new NetworkConnection()
            {
                LocalName = (string)obj.Properties["LocalName"].Value,
                Name = (string)obj.Properties["Name"].Value,
                RemotePath = (string)obj.Properties["RemotePath"].Value,
                UserName = (string)obj.Properties["UserName"].Value,
                IsPersistent = (bool)obj.Properties["Persistent"].Value,
                ConnectionState = (string)obj.Properties["ConnectionState"].Value
            };

            networkConnections.Add(networkConnection);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error($"Failed to get network connections.", ex);
    }

    return networkConnections;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using and the output you get when you run elevated and when you run normally please?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia I added the code.

Comment: If your mapped drives are mapped with non-elevated process, the elevated process can not "see" them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things but this is the only workaround I found.

**How to Enable EnableLinkedConnections**

1. Click **Start**, type **regedit** in the **Start programs and files** box, and
   then press ENTER.
2. Locate and then right-click the registry subkey
   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System**.
3. Point to **New**, and then click **DWORD** Value.
4. Type **EnableLinkedConnections**, and then press **ENTER**.
5. Right-click **EnableLinkedConnections**, and then click **Modify**.
6. In the Value data box, type **1**, and then click **OK**.
7. Exit Registry Editor, and then **restart the computer**.